# What does "address" mean in "addressing lattice sites"?

Tags: optical-lattices

In an [abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.10089) about "Sub-lattice-resolved imaging", the author was talking about local addressing of individual lattice sites:

> Here we introduce an imaging approach where matter wave optics magnifies the density distribution prior to optical imaging, allowing 2D sub-lattice spacing resolution in three-dimensional (3D) systems. Combining the site-resolved imaging with magnetic resonance techniques for **local addressing of individual lattice sites**, we demonstrate full accessibility to 2D local information and manipulation in 3D systems.

What does "address" mean in such a context?

Comment: They just mean if they want to modify the Hamiltonian to cause a specific atom at a specific lattice site to undergo some time-evolution, they can change that lattice site's Hamiltonian ("address" that lattice site) without also affecting the Hamiltonians of nearby lattice sites

Comment: So, it may mean "adjust that lattice site"?

Comment: It just means do SOMETHING to one lattice site, without affecting its neighbors

Comment: Could you add the reference to the quoted article?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I hyperlinked the mentioned abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that one is talking about a technique similar to [*single molecule spectroscopy*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-56544-1) (see also [here](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.physchem.48.1.181) or google for a review that is accessible to you - depending on your subscriptions). The idea is that all molecules/sites in a sample are subject to different Zeeman or Stark shifts - either due to the random fields present in the sample or due to fields specifically induced for this purpose. One can then optically manipulate ("address") the state of a single molecule by tuning the laser to its specific frequency (e.g., using EPR or NMR-like techniques or simply exciting it optically - depending on frequency and other properties).

A particular variation of this technique is when the transition frequency of a molecules/site is manipulated by bringing an AFM tip close to it - it is then the interaction with the tip that changes the frequency of the transition.